# Mazur's theorem-abelian torsion group of rational points of an elliptic curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

I am looking at Mazur's theorem...

$$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}, \text{ for } n=1,2, \dots ,10,12$$
means that the torsion group $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}$ contains the points $P$ which have the identity
$$nP=0, \text{ for } n=1,2, \dots ,10,12$$
and the coordinates are integers, right ??

What does
$$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/2m\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \text{ for } m=1,2,3,4$$
mean??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result specifies what are the exact possibilities for the torsion part of the group of *rational* points on an elliptic curve (over the rationals).

By Mordell's theorem you know that  $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}$ is some finite abelian group. Now, you know that it cannot by just whatever finite abelian group but it must be one of a very particular form.

Namely, the group is either cyclic with order $\le 10$ or equal to $12$ or it is a direct product of a group of order two with a cyclic group of order $2,4,6,$ or $8$.

For one particular elliptic curve it can be only one of these groups of course, but the result asserts that for every elliptic curves you will get one of these groups.

If the torsion part is cyclic, yes, this means about what you said: there is a point $P$ with *rational* coefficients on the group that has order $n$ where $n\le 10$ or $n=12$, and $P, 2P, \dots, nP=0$ is the set of all $n$ rational points of *finite* order on this curve.

For the other case, you have two points $P,Q$ the order of $P$ is $2$ the order of $Q$ is $n$ with $n$ equal $2,4,6,$ or $8$ and $Q,2Q, \dots ,n Q$ and $P+Q , P + 2Q, \dots , P+nQ$ is the set of all $2n$ rational points of finite order on this curve.

Comment: At $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}} \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$ why does $P$ have rational coefficients and not integer??

Comment: Because $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is the group of *rational* points on the curve. Why do you believe they should be integral?

Comment: $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is the group of rational points on the curve. Is the torsion group $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}$ the same?? There is the following in my notes: If $P(x, y) \in E(\mathbb{Q})$ and $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ or $y \notin \mathbb{Z}$, then $P$ has infinite order. $$E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}=\{P \in E(\mathbb{Q}) \ \ | \ \ P \text{ of finite order } \}$$

Comment: No, they are not the same. The torsion group is as you say the subgroup of points of finite order. Given the result you mention, it is then also true that the groups have integral coefficients. I am sorry I was just presently not aware of this result. However, it might be worth noting that this, the integrality, is somewhat of a  separate matter. Strictly from what you wrote in OP, one does not know the integrality of the points (while it is true in view of the additional result you now mentioned).

Comment: Ok... Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: You are welcome. And thanks to you for bringing that result to my attention.